# set threshold for the probability result from decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, threshold, confusion-matrix

I tried to calculate the confusion matrix after I conduct the decision tree model

```
# tree model
tree <- rpart(LoanStatus_B ~.,data=train, method='class')
# confusion matrix
pdata <- predict(tree, newdata = test, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(data = pdata, reference = test$LoanStatus_B, positive = "1")
```

How can I set the threshold to my confusion matrix, say maybe I want probability above 0.2 as default, which is the binary outcome.

Comment: Have a look at `?predict.rpart` to see what else you could specify for `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things to note here. Firstly, make sure you're getting class probabilities when you do your predictions. With prediction type `="class"` you were just getting discrete classes, so what you wanted would've been impossible. So you'll want to make it `"p"` like mine below.

```
library(rpart)
data(iris)

iris$Y <- ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa",1,0)

# tree model
tree <- rpart(Y ~Sepal.Width,data=iris, method='class')

# predictions
pdata <- as.data.frame(predict(tree, newdata = iris, type = "p"))
head(pdata)

# confusion matrix
table(iris$Y, pdata$`1` > .5)
```

Next note that .5 here is just an arbitrary value -- you can change it to whatever you want.

I don't see a reason to use the `confusionMatrix` function, when a confusion matrix can be created simply this way and allows you to acheive your goal of easily changing the cutoff.

Having said that, if you do want to use the `confusionMatrix` function for your confusion matrix, then just create a discrete class prediction first based on your custom cutoff like this:

```
pdata$my_custom_predicted_class <- ifelse(pdata$`1` > .5, 1, 0)
```

Where, again, .5 is your custom chosen cutoff and can be anything you want it to be.

```
caret::confusionMatrix(data = pdata$my_custom_predicted_class, 
                  reference = iris$Y, positive = "1")
```

> ```
> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
>
>           Reference
> Prediction  0  1
>          0 94 19
>          1  6 31
>
>                Accuracy : 0.8333          
>                  95% CI : (0.7639, 0.8891)
>     No Information Rate : 0.6667          
>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 3.661e-06       
>
>                   Kappa : 0.5989          
>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.0164          
>
>             Sensitivity : 0.6200          
>             Specificity : 0.9400          
>          Pos Pred Value : 0.8378          
>          Neg Pred Value : 0.8319          
>              Prevalence : 0.3333          
>          Detection Rate : 0.2067          
>    Detection Prevalence : 0.2467          
>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7800          
>
>        'Positive' Class : 1
> ```

Comment: Got it . Thank you so much! One simple quesion : type = "p" what is this doing there?

Comment: @PumpkinC You're welcome; "p" means probabilities. It's saying to give the predicted probabilities for each class